# Example of a function with an discrete domain but an continuous range?

Tags: functions

Out of curiousity, are there functions who's domain is discrete but the range is continuous? Furthermore, is there also a real-world example of such a function, in physics for instance?

Comment: What do you mean by a set being continuous?

Comment: Reading this again after some time, I wonder if this was really about a continuous range with a surjective function. A continuous range would be a set which could be bijectively mapped to $[0,1]$. The surjective function would mean that an uncountable set is enumerable, which is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$
f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R} \\
f(k) = 1 / k
$$

- The domain consists of the positive integers, thus discrete.
- The range consists of the real numbers, which are continuous.
- The image $f(\mathbb{N})$ is a set of discrete real numbers.

Comment: You should probably replace$1/k$ by $1/(k+1)$ (since $0\in\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: I used the definition as positive integers (k > 0).

Comment: What do you mean by a set being continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Example: A probability distribution of the number of children women have.  The domain is the integer number of children. The range is the probability of a woman having that many, which is a continuous variable.